# How to use filter mediator to check json content

Tags: json, wso2, wso2-esb

I use below code to check whether content has value.

But the xpath results in error.

What can I do to change the xpath?

The xpath error message is

> :org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2MessageContext cannot be cast to org.apache.axiom.om.OMNode

```
<filter xpath="json-eval($.data.content)">
    <then>
         <property expression="json-eval($.data.content)" name="filters" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    </then>
   <else/>
</filter>
```

Comment: Extract the json expression as a property and use it inside the filter mediator. It will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending upon your use-case, you can utilize **Switch** or **filter** mediators as following.

```
<switch source="json-eval($.data.content)">
        <case regex="urData">

        </case>
        <default>

        </default>
</switch>
```

In case of Filter mediators, the data can be set into a property and then processed.

```
<property action="set" name="dataProp" scope="default" type="STRING" expression="json-eval($.data.content)"/>

<filter regex="true" source="boolean(get-property('dataProp'))">
```